# Cannot link Jquery-ui autocomplete to JSON file

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I realise this question has been asked before, however from looking through the other topics I still cannot find the solution to my problem.

Here the relevant JS code + plunk of the problem;

```
    $('#test').autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "brands.json",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: request,
                    success: function(data) {
                        response($.map(data, function(item) {
                            return (item.brands)
                        }));
                    }
                });
            },
```

Plunk:

https://plnkr.co/edit/qEZnuszj7JkNy1NrGyCd?p=preview

As you can see, I'm unable to retrieve any of the data stated in the .JSON file.

Any help will be much appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: why not just `return data.brands;` in response()?

Comment: The closing of your `$(document).ready();` is wrong on line 53. Line 52 should read: `}, 100);` and Line 53 should read: `});`.

Comment: I do not see elements in your HTML that have `test` as an ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along with the other comments I made, I made a working example in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/xp43u291/

**HTML**

```
<input name="myList" id="test">
<span id="#message"></span>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#test').autocomplete({
      source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "brands.json",
          dataType: "JSON",
          type: "GET",
          success: function(resp) {
            console.log("Find '", request.term, "' in ", resp.brands);
            var results = [];
            $.each(resp.brands, function(k, v) {
              if (v.indexOf(request.term) == 0) {
                results.push(v);
              }
            });
            response(results);
          }
        });
      },
      autoFocus: true,
      minLength: 3,
      response: function(event, ui) {
        if (!ui.content.length) {
          var noResult = {
            value: "",
            label: "No results found"
          };
          ui.content.push(noResult);
        } else {
          $("#message").empty();
        }
      }
    });

    var render = $('#test').autocomplete('instance')._renderMenu;
    $('#test').autocomplete('instance')._renderMenu = function(ul, items) {
      items.push({
        label: 'OTHER BRAND',
        value: 'OTHER BRAND',
        last: true
      });
      render.call(this, ul, items);
    };
  }, 100);
});
```

First, you do not want to use `$(document).ready();` and `$(function(){});`. Use one or the other.

Second, since you're calling a JSON file and not a script, there is nothing to pass to the file itself. So we remove the `data` option.

Third, on `success`, we are expecting JSON data back as an Object. IT will come back with all the data and we'll want to pair it down to just the results that match our `request.term` or the string that has been entered. You can do this in many ways, I went with an easy loop, using `.indexOf()`. You can change this from `==0` to `>=0` too if you want it to seek in the entire phrase versus just the beginning.

I hope that helps address this issue for you. If not, comment or update your post.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help so far - your code looks a lot cleaner than mine! When i put a search for 'dom' or something that is contained in the JSON file on your plnkr, it still doesn't show the correct result however? it just carries on returning the no results found / other brand list options.

Comment: Then you need to Upper Case the search. `.indexOf()` is case sensitive. If you search for 'DOM' it will come right up. So either update your data or convert use `request.term.toUpperCase();` I like pretty code and if you ever work in Python, you MUST format properly. So I just do it everywhere. Plus the 'Tidy' features help a lot ;)

Comment: ahh okay! I've got everything to work now, Thanks again for the answer, it's very well explained and seems to be a very sophisticated solution!